# How to change the date format in sql queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have date and time format as

```
2011-12-31 05:12:23
```

And i need to change it as follows:

```
Monday @ 2:23AM 21/11/2011
```

I am using this sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM cms_content order by ID DESC;
```

where i have the fields as follows in my table named cms_content:

```
id, idname, author, date, title, body
```

So how to do this so that i can get the desired result?

Comment: yes i googled and found something like this: select convert(varchar, getdate(), 100), but i don't know how to put in between the sql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`,  '%W @ %l:%i%p %d/%m/%Y') FROM cms_content
```

Read further here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

[edit : additional]

I noticed a difference between your sample and expected data output so here's a literal `answer` to your date format inquiry:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( DATE_ADD('2011-12-31 05:12:23', INTERVAL '-40 2:49' DAY_MINUTE ) ,  '%W @ %l:%i%p %d/%m/%Y' )
```

Comment: It is giving a parse error:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@'

Comment: Ok, i did it, the problem that it was creating is that it accepted double inverted comma(") instead of single inverted comma(')..:)

Comment: By the way, I noticed a time difference between your sample data and its expected output so I modified the post, @AmitYadav , to reflect it